# How to Avoid Direct object instantiation for default library

Tags: magento2

I used default library of soap. I created a object using new keyword:

```
new \SoapVar(
            $this->merchantId,
            XSD_STRING,
            null,
            $nameSpace,
            null,
            $nameSpace
        );
```

but in magento2 Direct object instantiation is discouraged. So how can I get the object of `new \SoapVar` without calling it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Create/use an interface and map it in di.xml so you can use it as dependency injection? You might have to write a factory for it as well.

But Magento discourages instantiation of Magento objects if I'm not mistaking. 3rd party libraries don't apply to these guidelines.

Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Thanks for reply but Mangento also discourages instantiation of third party library you can refer this tool https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp